# Is there any way I can navigate to a link using options in html using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, search, response.redirect

I created a list of options using html and placed a button beneath it...I want the user to select an option and when he clicks on the button,it redirects him to a different page...
Is there anyway that I can do this using JavaScript please?

Comment: Is the button submitting or setting some data?  Or is it just a link?  Based on what you have described it sounds like you could potentially be creating a weird accessibility issue while simultaneously adding more clicks than needed for what may essentially just be a nav...

Comment: Let me make it simple ..I used the <select> tag and it contains a list of options.... And I created a button beneath the select button, so I just want  to create a function that, whenever a user selects from the list of options and click on the button,it redirects him to an html page of that selected option

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `window.location.href = "/someLocation"` just is made for you.

Answer (score 0):

when you click in the button you can call a function and inside of this function you put
`window.location.href = "your-url"`
or you can use `window.open("your-url")` to open a new tab.

```html
<select onChange="goToPage(value)">
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="https://google.com" > google </option>
  <option value="https://stackoverflow.com" > stackOverflw </option>
  <option value="https://github.com" > git </option>
</select> 
 
<script>
  function goToPage(value) {
    window.location.href = value
  }
</script>
```

you an see more in this
[link here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50432/onclick-numa-option-select)